# Grails custom taglib cannot use custom artefact during integration test

Tags: testing, grails, grails-plugin, taglib, grails-2.0

I have written a plugin containing a custom TagLib which itself uses a custom artefact instances. The taglib works exactly as expected when the plugin is included in an application. However, I am unable to unable to write an integration test for it.

Let's say the custom artefact type is "Foo" and the artefact handler class is `FooArtefactHandler`

The (simplified) `FooTagLib` class looks like this:

```java
class FooTagLib {

    static namespace = "bar"

    def eachFoo = { attrs, body ->
        grailsApplication.fooClasses.each { foo ->
            out << body()
        }
    }
}
```

The associated `FooTagLibTests` class looks like this:

```java
import grails.test.mixin.*

@TestFor(FooTagLib)
class FooTagLibTests {

    void testEachFoo() {
        grailsApplication.registerArtefactHandler(new FooArtefactHandler())
        // Classes AFoo and BFoo are in the test/integration folder
        grailsApplication.addArtefact(FooArtefactHandler.TYPE, AFoo)
        grailsApplication.addArtefact(FooArtefactHandler.TYPE, BFoo)
        // just to check if artefacts are correctly loaded
        assert grailsApplication.fooClasses.length == 2

        assert applyTemplate("<bar:eachFoo>baz</bar:eachFoo>") == "bazbaz"
    }
}
```

When I run this test, the result is the following:

```java
| Failure:  testeachFoo(com.my.package.FooTagLibTests)
|  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <bar:eachFoo>: No such property: fooClasses for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication
```

The`grailsApplication` in the taglib does not seem to be the same instance as the one in the test. Can someone explain this to me? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an integration test you shouldn't use `@TestFor`, instead, extends `GroovyPagesTestCase` and declare grailsApplication:

```
class FooTagLibTests extends GroovyPagesTestCase {

    def grailsApplication

    void testEachFoo() {
        grailsApplication.registerArtefactHandler(new FooArtefactHandler())
        // Classes AFoo and BFoo are in the test/integration folder
        grailsApplication.addArtefact(FooArtefactHandler.TYPE, AFoo)
        grailsApplication.addArtefact(FooArtefactHandler.TYPE, BFoo)
        // just to check if artefacts are correctly loaded
        assert grailsApplication.fooClasses.length == 2

        assert applyTemplate("<bar:eachFoo>baz</bar:eachFoo>") == "bazbaz"
    }
}
```

That's because TestFor annotation will mock an instance of grailsApplication (used in unit tests).